# What does it mean for a pivotal quantity to be monotone in $\theta$?

Tags: statistics, monotone-functions, confidence-interval

I'm told that a pivotal quantity is a function $g(\mathbf X,\theta)$ of the data $\mathbf X$ and the parameter $\theta$, satisfying

1. The distribution of $g(\mathbf X,\theta)$ is known and independent of $\theta$,
2. For each ﬁxed $\mathbf X$, $g(\mathbf X,\theta)$ is a monotonic function of $\theta$.

I do not understand the 2nd criterion. Why does $\mathbf X$ need to be fixed? What does it mean for $g(\mathbf X,\theta)$ to be a monotonic function of $\theta$? Why does it need to be monotonic?

Comment: Ideally, the function $g(\mathbf X,\theta)$ has to be such that we can derive a confidence interval for $\theta$ from it by solving a string of inequalities. Maybe that's where 'monotonic' comes from.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes indeed, my source material shows the pivotal quantity being used to derive a CI for $\theta$. Why does $g$ being a monotonic function of $\theta$ help us solve the string of inequalities?

Comment: Maybe for saying something like $g(\theta)\le t\implies \theta\le g^{-1}(t)$ or $\theta\ge g^{-1}(t)$ where $t$ is a function of the data.